# SQL update performance in concurrent case

Tags: sql, locking, database-performance, hana

My case is that I have 50 threads to run the same tasks(processing different staff, but the same process pattern) concurrently, but the execution time result usually has some time spikes like the following:

```
1.62s
1.47s
1.44s
1.4s
0.8s
0.8s
0.8s
....
```

You see, the first top time duration are much larger than the stable ones. I called them time spikes.

After test many times, I figured out that there is a SQL update statement in my task execution cause the issue. The update statement will change the same table.

```
UPDATE aTable A SET A.STATUS = 'COMPLETED', A.END_TIME = NOW(), A.PROGRESS_PERCENT = 100 
WHERE A.TASK_EXECUTION_ID = XXXX
```

So I break it down. When I execute

```
UPDATE aTable A SET A.STATUS = 'COMPLETED', A.END_TIME = NOW() 
WHERE A.TASK_EXECUTION_ID = XXXX
```

Everything is fine, and there is no time spike. However, after I add the progress percent = 100 back to the statement. The spikes happens again.

Does anyone knows the reason and solution? Lock contention?

Comment: What storage engine is being used for the database/table in question? What type of column is progress_percent?

Comment: Thanks for caring about this issue. Database is SAP HANA. progress_percent is INTEGER. Since I suspect something is related with the R/W lock contention under such a concurrent scenario, I make the thread sleep for a very short random time when doing this update. It works. But this still confuses me.

Comment: You may get better responses if you remove the sql and mysqli tags from your question and add SAP HANA. Your question does not appear to be directly related to sql or mysqli.

Comment: thanks. I moved it.

Comment: Is this a column store or a row store table? And does the 50 parallel update all address the same TASK_EXECUTION_ID? How many records are affected by each update?

Comment: @LarsBr. Thanks for replying. It is column store, 50 thread address the same task plan, but don't have the same id. I did some experiments on different hana box with different cores, and found out the spike issue is related with the hyper threaded core number of the hana box. So now I don't need to focus on the spike issue, and i will focus on other performance improvement.

Comment: Re-reading the question I get the impression that the execution time spikes are occurring over time and are not directly linked to the no. of concurrent update threads. So - without further data - we're left a bit to guessing here, but have you checked whether a column store delta merge or a savepoint is happening during the update?

Comment: I haven't checked the column store, but when i did the perf test, I set savepoint as 0. Thanks for your help.